# Show default paragraph again on mouseout of a non-default paragraph

Tags: jquery, elementor

1. When I do not click with the cursor on all icons it shows the general paragraph "Lorem Ipsum...etc"
2. When I click with the cursor on the Facebook icon so it show facebook's paragraph and it hides the general paragraph "Lorem Ipsum...etc"
3. When I get the cursor away again from Facebook's icon it must show the general paragraph "Lorem Ipsum...etc" again

I have used this code but the only issue I do not know how to show and hide the general paragraph "Lorem Ipsum...etc"

Can anyone advise me?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $ = jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-showme]').hover( function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var showme = $(this).attr('data-showme')
        
        $('.all-img').hide()
        $('.' + showme).show()
        
    })
})
</script>
```

I use attributes: data-showme|img
and css classes: all-img img

[image: General Paragraph]

[image: Facebook Paragraph]

Comment: No one will be able to help you out if you don't post the actual HTML

Comment: Also `event.preventDefault()` should def throw an error in the snippet above, as it's not defined

Answer (score 0):

It's the normal behavior of the code to do that. If you want a mouse out event you should set that event accordingly.

So the code could look something like this

```
script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $ = jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-showme]').hover( function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var showme = $(this).attr('data-showme')
        
        $('.all-img').hide()
        $('.' + showme).show()
        
    })
$('[data-showme]').mouseout ( () => { $('.all-img').hide() } ) ;
})
</script>
```